# Needing help on printing mode in java

Tags: arraylist, methods, mode

I am given a task to make a method that takes a parameter of an ArrayList of Integer obj and print out the sum, average, and mode.

I can't seem to figure out how to find the mode. It should print out the number if there is only one mode, and it should print out "no single mode" if there is more than one (or none) mode. My method only prints out "no single mode". How can I fix my code to have the mode printed out?

This is what I have for my code:

```
public static void printStatistics(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
int sum = 0;
for(int i : arr){
  sum += i;
}
System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
System.out.println("Average: "+(double)sum/arr.size());

int temp = 0, counter = 0, max = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < arr.size() - 1; j++){
  for(int k = j+1; k < arr.size(); k++){
    if(arr.get(j) == arr.get(k)){
      counter++;
      
      if(counter > max){
        max = counter;
        temp = arr.get(j);
      }
      if(counter == max){
        temp = -1;
      }
    }
  }
}
if(temp > 0){
  System.out.println("Mode: "+temp);
}
else if(temp < 0){
  System.out.println("Mode: no single mode");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here

```
if(counter > max){
    max = counter;
    temp = arr.get(j);
}
if(counter == max){
    temp = -1;
}
```

You are assigning the value of `counter` to `max` in the first condition so the second `if` condition i.e., `if(counter == max)` will always be `true`, which results in `temp` having the value `-1` which fulfills `else if(temp < 0)`. This is why you are getting `Mode: no single mode` as the output every time.

---

Changing the condition should give you the desired output

```
if(counter < max){
    temp = -1;
}
```